# RoR - Adding TestRun in a test case management system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Edit - I am rephrasing the question

No longer need the answer for nested routes.

I have create a testcase management system with the following resources
Projects -> has many Suites -> has many test cases

I want to add a new feature/functionality of test run. For every release, I want to make a new testrun, in which I will include only selected suites/testcases.

Flow will be like:
click and create - new testrun
select (from dropdown or checkboxes) - suites which need to be run for the current release
then select test cases from those suites

How to go about it? Should I create a new resource testrun? and then how do i add suites to it everytime?

Thanks for previous and future answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer myself. I am using a join table though - has_many :through
I am creating a new able called test results and here is how the associations go

```
class Testcase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :testresults
  has_many :testruns, :through => :testresults


class Testrun < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :testresults
  has_many :testcases, :through => :testresults


class Testresult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :testrun
  belongs_to :testcase
```

The thing I need to figure out is how to insert the result in Testresult table now